# Using ElasticSearch in GitLab, what happens if ES Container goes down?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Our company wants to enable ES on GitLab so that we can search through all repo's and have advanced search. We are thinking of hosting the ES service ourselves (instead of paying for Amazon ES Instance or ElasticCloud) but want to understand how the failsafe works first.

For example, if we enable ES in the GitLab admin settings page and then our ES instance were to go down, does GitLab then revert back to original search or is search just completely down?

Thanks

Comment: I believe it reverts to regular search but best to confirm with GitLab support

Comment: It goes down and you will get a 5xx error from gitlab

Answer (score 1):

You get a "500 Whoops, something went wrong on our end." You need to login to gitlab and in system/integrations uncheck "Search with Elasticsearch enabled" until your ES container is back up.